# How can I stop a HTML page after the <head>...</head> loads using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a URL rewriting proxy server (EZproxy) that can be set up like this to provide one-click access to target URL's, providing an authentication challenge when needed but getting out of the way when it's not needed.

http://url-rewriting-proxy-server.com/login?url=http://target-url.com

I would like load a URL like above and then stop the page, only loading the `<head></head>`.

I would like to use a bookmarklet (server side code is OK) to accomplish this.

Can I do this programmatically with Javascript? If so, how? If Javascript is a bad idea, are there alternatives?

Will your solution work in Mobile Safari?

Comment: You are missing something from your question... "I would like load a URL like above and then stop the page, only loading the..." .. the?

Comment: Make you body tag empty then when you are ready, using ajax, load the body content and simply add it to the DOM.  Look at JQuery

Comment: How about the "Location" and "Refresh" in header?

Comment: Why would you want to stop a page loading the body?

Comment: When http://url-rewriting-proxy-server.com/login?url=http://target-url.com loads, it rewrites the URL to http://url-rewriting-proxy-server.com:[port number]/sub-pages. This is a standard authentication system used in academic libraries and the port numbers change with every session and every user. If I can stop the page load before the URL is loaded, I could probably bookmark pages like http://url-rewriting-proxy-server.com/login?url=http://target-url.com on the homescreen in Mobile Safari.

Comment: If URL rewriting is going on, then stopping execution half way through loading the HTML document won't help - it's far too late for that.

Comment: Ah, then there's a strong possibility I'm looking down the wrong trail for this solution. When I take a look at the pages, nothing is passed off to the proxy server until after the page has loaded, the scripts are all at the end of the document. I have a whitelist of hosts and rules for rewriting, and if something isn't on the whitelist, it just loads another HTML page. It's not particularly sophisticated, but it's a stable, effective and standard system. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
 window.stop();
```

is what you are looking for

Comment: Tried, and failed. widow.stop(); is certainly part of the solution, but the matter of having it happen at the right time and place is currently escaping me.